# Setting Prompt to Read Only

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I am setting a variable equal to the input from a prompt and it's then passed and use to display on my page. However, I do not think prompt is what I need to be using but I have no idea how to do it otherwise. Essentially once it prompts them it has their email already in the prompt box and this is what I want, but I don't want them to be able to change the field to avoid the input of a different email than the one set with their session. Any advice? My code is below.

```
    selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Confirm Email:','<?php echo "{$_SESSION['email']}"; ?>');



   if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
       url: 'add_events.php',
       data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
       alert('Added Successfully');
       }
   });
```

Comment: than why are you using the value? Why are you not using confirm?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you don't want them to alter the email, don't use `prompt` or `confirm` or any other JavaScript method, just show the email in the page's HTML.

Comment: "I don't want them to be able to change the field to avoid the input of a different email than the one set with their session" ...then when it's submitted to the server just use the email stored in the session. Don't even bother putting it into the ajax request or anything. Why are you even interacting with the user about it? If you don't want them to confirm it or change it, then don't show it... (or just put it in a plain old div or something somewhere else in the page). It need not be used anywhere in your JS code.

Comment: `but I don't want them to be able to change the field to avoid the input of a different email`  that is what the attribute readonly is for.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix hmm, yes but also the result is being used to send back in the ajax call...and a user could still interfere with that if they wanted to...so actually better to just drop it entirely from the client-side code, and get the value out of the session when the ajax request arrives at the server.

Comment: User's click on the calendar at the time in which they want and then then basically the value of the 'var title' is being used to display on my calendar along with the time they chose.

Comment: @Trevor if you don't want the user to be able to amend the title then simply don't ask them about it. It seems you are not adding the event directly into fullCalendar, but instead sending it to the server. So if the title must always be the email stored in the session, then when add_events.php runs, just pick the email out of the session at that time, and use it as the title when you save the event to your database. You don't have to bother sending "title" field in the ajax request, or asking the user to input it.

Comment: @ADyson Okay that makes sense. I will try and do so. Thank you very much for your help, never really done anything with Ajax so it's all new. Appreciate it!

Comment: @Trevor no problem. P.S. this concept would not be specific to ajax - the same would apply if you were doing a traditional form postback. It's more to do with the source of the data - in this case, you already have the correct data on the server, so there's no need to request it again from the client, especially since there's the potential for it to be modified (legitimately or otherwise) and cause invalid data to be submitted to your database.

Comment: @ADyson Whenever they click on the calendar that is when they are prompted and their input is used to display on the calendar. Whenever they click on the calendar could I just do a confirm to ensure that's the time they want and if they confirm it just takes that request and puts to their email on the calendar?

Comment: @Trevor Well, how are you adding events to the calendar itself? Do you use `renderEvent` client-side, or do you just wait till the add_events has completed and then run `refetchEvents`? P.S. I added an answer to your initial main question below.

Comment: @ADyson render event! and thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. If the answer has helped you, please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick mark next to the answer so it turns green) - thanks :-)

Comment: If you're using eventRender directly, then you can just inject the email value from the Session into the JS, e.g. `var event = { title: "<?php echo $_SESSION["email"]; ?>", start: start, end: end };` then it's effectively hard-coded (This little example is assuming start and end are from the "select" callback's inputs - I guess you would create this object in the "success" callback of your ajax, so you know the event was added successfully before placing it on the calendar).

Comment: @ADyson Definitely did! Since I am new to stackoverflow and don't have a reputation build it is hidden, but definitely an upvote from me! Thank you I will definitely try that out.

Comment: You can't upvote until you have a bit more reputation, but you should be able to "accept" answers already, they are two different actions.

Comment: I got you! Thanks once again. @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the user to be able to amend the title then simply don't ask them about it. It seems you are not adding the event directly into fullCalendar, but instead sending it to the server (and presumably after that you cause fullCalendar to re-fetch the events from the server, I would assume, although it's not shown).

So if the title must always be the email stored in the session, then when add_events.php runs, just pick the email out of the session at that time, and use it as the title when you save the event to your database. You don't have to bother sending "title" field in the ajax request, or asking the user to input it.

The client-side code snippet you've shown could then be modified to:

```
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {

if (title) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
       url: 'add_events.php',
       data: 'start='+ start +'&end='+ end,
       type: "POST",
       success: function(json) {
       alert('Added Successfully');
       }
   });
```

Without seeing the server-side code I can't advise specifically but it's likely you may want to do something whereby you now read the "title" field from $_SESSION rather than $_POST when collecting the data to write into the database.

Answer (score -1):

So you are using prompt as a confirmation? You should be using [`window.confirm('message')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)

```
var title = '<?php echo "{$_SESSION['email']}"; ?>';
var check = window.prompt('Confirm Email: ' + title);
if (check) {

}
```

but if it is part of the session, why are you not just reading it from the session on the server?